# ASP.NET Multiple trigger doesn't work properly

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, timer

I'm implementing a page using updatepanel and some triggers.

What I want to implement is below.

1. Timer(timer1) updates UpdatePanel(update_content) at intervals of 10 seconds.
2. If User handle RadioButtonList(rbl_axis), ListBox(list_point),
   **immediately** update UpdatePanel.
3. All update occurs by **asynchronous**.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            div_title.InnerText= "Hello";

            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(rbl_axis);
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(list_point);
            printTime("Page_Load");

        }   
    }

    protected void printTime(string message)
    {
        div_content.InnerHtml += message +": "+ DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "<br />";
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printTime("<font color='red'>Timer</font>");
    }

    protected void rbl_axis_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printTime("Axis("+rbl_axis.SelectedValue+")");
    }

    protected void list_point_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printTime(list_point.SelectedValue);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_axis" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_axis_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="X" Value="X" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Y" Value="Y" ></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Z" Value="Z" ></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            <asp:ListBox ID="list_point" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100px" Height="100px"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="list_point_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Point1" Value="Point1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Point2" Value="Point2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Point3" Value="Point3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Point4" Value="Point4"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Point5" Value="Point5"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update_content" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="div_title" runat="server"></div>
                    <div id="div_content" runat="server"></div>
                </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doen't work properly.

Update Panel updates only by Timer.

If i handle the list box and radio button control, Update panel does't update.

And at the next Timer Tick, list box and radio button control's modification is applied.

How can I implement what i want.

Can you please give me some advice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your RadioButtonList and ListBox must set the AutoPostBack property to true in order to trigger a postback.

Also you need to register these postback events to the UpdatePanel, pretty much the way you did with the Timer Click event.

For example, you code could be more like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_axis" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_axis_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="X" Value="X" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Y" Value="Y" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Z" Value="Z" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:ListBox ID="list_point" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100px"
    Height="100px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="list_point_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Point1" Value="Point1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Point2" Value="Point2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Point3" Value="Point3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Point4" Value="Point4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Point5" Value="Point5"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="update_content" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbl_axis" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="list_point" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="div_title" runat="server"></div>
        <div id="div_content" runat="server"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```